# Restricting Access to Contribution Module

Tags: accessibility

Is it possible to restrict access to the contribution module section of CIVICRM yet giving a person access to all the other portions of the program including contacts/groups, etc.?  We only want certain individuals entering contributions and seeing who gave what.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mark - Pradeep's answer below should answer your question.  In the future, always make sure to include the version of civi you are using and what CMS. (Wordpress, Drupal, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Its possible to give access to Contribution component to specific roles. You can set the permission to access different components at

**For Drupal:**

```
Navigate to CiviCRM >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions(Access Control) and click on **Drupal Access Control**.
```

**For Wordpress:**

```
Navigate to CiviCRM >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions(Access Control) and click on **Wordpress Access Control**.
```

HTH

Pradeep